# Find the value of $k$ which will mean that these simultaneous equations have a consistent but not a unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

> > The question is: Find the value of $k$ which will mean that these simultaneous equations have a consistent but not a unique solution.
> >
> > $$ 2x-2y+z = 10 $$
> >
> > $$ 3x+y-3z = 18 $$
> >
> > $$ x-5y+5z=k$$

I know I can use linear combination to find the value of k as such:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&-2&1&10\\
      3&1&-3&18\\
      1&-5&5&k\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$$\left[
        \begin{array}{ccc|c} 
        4 & -4 & 2 & 20\\
        -3 & -1 & 3 &-18\\
        1 & -5 & 5 &k\\
        \end{array}
\right]
$$

Multiplying first row by $2$ and second by $-1$

Hence $$ 20 - 18 = k $$

$$ k = 2 $$

However I was wondering what alternative methods are there to solve this question?

Is it possible to use the determinant? (I have been searching about detrerminants and I was having trouble applying it in this system of equations).

Comment: @Moo, I guess misread the question. It requires non-unique solution, so it must be zero.

Comment: Sorry what is consistent?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot use determinant here. You can see it this way. Determinant is defined on square matrix. In this problem, only the left-hand side of the equations constitutes a square matrix, but $k$ appears in the right-hand side. The determinant does not involve $k$ here.

In a rigorous way, determinant can only determine whether the system 1)has a unique solution ($det\neq 0$) or 2) has no solution or has infinite solution ($det=0$). Determinant cannot distinguish the two possibilities in the latter case.

Your trial is right to me.